# Текст из json в переменную через запятую

Tags: php

Есть вот такой список

```
 [{
    "pos": 1,
    "uid": "44420575",
    "rating": "14130271"
}, {
    "pos": 2,
    "uid": "24055142",
    "rating": "1657068"
}, {
    "pos": 3,
    "uid": "29846213",
    "rating": "1592081"
}]
```

Как uid - ы из json занести в переменную $uids через запятую (44420575,24055142,29846213)

Пробовал так

```
implode(',', array_column(json_decode($json, true) , 'uid'));
```

Comment: Всё работает как надо, только array_column работает только в php `>=5.5`

Comment: А может можно как то по другому это реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так можно заменить

```
<?php
$json='[{
    "pos": 1,
    "uid": "44420575",
    "rating": "14130271"
}, {
    "pos": 2,
    "uid": "24055142",
    "rating": "1657068"
}, {
    "pos": 3,
    "uid": "29846213",
    "rating": "1592081"
}]';

echo implode(',',array_map(function($e) {return $e['uid'];},json_decode($json, true)));
```

http://ideone.com/vbZ0O0

Answer (score 1):

А можно еще циклом перебрать:

```
$json = '[{
    "pos": 1,
    "uid": "44420575",
    "rating": "14130271"
}, {
    "pos": 2,
    "uid": "24055142",
    "rating": "1657068"
}, {
    "pos": 3,
    "uid": "29846213",
    "rating": "1592081"
}]';
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
$count = count($jsonArray);
$uids = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $uids .= $jsonArray[$i]['uid'] . ', ';
}
echo $uids;
```